# Reopening google colab causes cell to print everything

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

A standard way to clear jupyter notebook’s cell output is to use IPython’s `clear_output()` or output.clear() from `google.colab`. Say I have a loop that clears the output and prints something new at each iteration

```
from google.colab import output
for i in range(1000):
  output.clear(wait=True)
  sys.stdout.write(str(i)+'\n')
  time.sleep(10)
```

This loop is obviously gna run for a long time so naturally I closed the window. However, closing and reopening the colab notebook page causes ALL the `sys.stdout.write` messages to be displayed, despite they should have been cleared in each iteration and only the latest `i` should be shown. What can I do to fix this behavior?

Comment: `sys.stdout` is buffered.  When the window is closed, apparently all the output is buffered up until the window is available again, so there was nothing for `output.clear` to clear.  You could use `\r` instead of `\n` so that the lines overwrite themselves.

Comment: @TimRoberts I guess that works if I am just printing a single line each time. Are there alternatives where I can clear the buffer of `sys.stdout` each time after a message is print?

Comment: In the long term, does it really matter?  You're never going to deliver a Jupyter notebook as a production solution.  You'll use a command-line script or a UI script, where you'll manage things like this in a better way.

Comment: That is a good point. I just thought that when training models for ML for example, it might be nice to have a multi-line status indicator without overwhelming the browser. Anyways, I ended up finding a work around using Jupyter's `display` function instead of print.